# Deleting everything between two quotes in a string

Tags: c++, strings

Is this the easiest way to delete everything between and including the two first quotes (if present) in an `std::wstring`?

```
unsigned int firstQuotePos = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"");
unsigned int secondQuotePos = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"", firstQuotePos + 1);

if (firstQuotePos != std::wstring::npos && secondQuotePos != std::wstring::npos)
{
    logFileName = std::wstring(logFileName.begin(), logFileName.begin() + firstQuotePos)
        + std::wstring(logFileName.begin() + secondQuotePos + 1, logFileName.end());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is very picky about types.
You should always try and use the correct ones:

```
unsigned int firstQuotePos = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"");
unsigned int secondQuotePos = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"", firstQuotePos + 1);
```

should be:

```
std::string::size_type firstQuotePos  = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"");
std::string::size_type secondQuotePos = logFileName.find_first_of(L"\"", firstQuotePos + 1);
```

Next there is already an erase that does this:

```
if (firstQuotePos != std::string::npos)
{
    logFileName.erase(firstQuotePos, (secondQuotePos - firstQuotePos));
}
```